# How to implement "i++ and i>=max ? 0: i" that only use atomic in Go

Tags: go, locking, atomic, cas

only use atomic implement the follow code:

```
const Max = 8
var index int
func add() int {
    index++
    if index >= Max {
        index = 0
    }
    return index
}
```

such as:

```
func add() int {
    atomic.AddUint32(&index, 1)
    // error: race condition 
    atomic.CompareAndSwapUint32(&index, Max, 0)
    return index
}
```

but it is wrong. there is a race condition. 
can be implemented that don't use lock ?

Comment: You need a CAS (compare and swap) loop

Comment: @Ivan can you elaborate? The implementation in the question already uses CAS, can you explain the concept of a CAS loop?

Comment: Your race isn't in the atomic operations, look at the exact location the race detector is showing you. You're reading the `index` value in your return statement.

Comment: @mhutter I don't really know Go and I don't have compiler with me atm. I can only show use example in either pseudo-code or C (or C++). It might be converted to Go with some help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Solving it without loops and locks

A simple implementation may look like this:

```
const Max = 8

var index int64

func Inc() int64 {
    value := atomic.AddInt64(&index, 1)
    if value < Max {
        return value // We're done
    }

    // Must normalize, optionally reset:
    value %= Max
    if value == 0 {
        atomic.AddInt64(&index, -Max) // Reset
    }
    return value
}
```

How does it work?

It simply adds 1 to the counter; [`atomic.AddInt64()`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/atomic/#AddInt64) returns the new value. If it's less than `Max`, "we're done", we can return it.

If it's greater than or equal to `Max`, then we have to normalize the value (make sure it's in the range `[0..Max)`) and reset the counter.

Reset may only be done by a single caller (a single goroutine), which will be selected by the counter's value. The winner will be the one that caused the counter to reach `Max`.

And the trick to avoid the need of locks is to reset it by adding `-Max`, not by setting it to `0`. Since the counter's value is normalized, it won't cause any problems if other goroutines are calling it and incrementing it concurrently.

Of course with many goroutines calling this `Inc()` concurrently it may be that the counter will be incremented more that `Max` times before a goroutine that ought to reset it can actually carry out the reset, which would cause the counter to reach or exceed `2 * Max` or even `3 * Max` (in general: `n * Max`). So we handle this by using a `value % Max == 0` condition to decide if a reset should happen, which again will only happen at a single goroutine for each possible values of `n`.

### Simplification

Note that the normalization does not change values already in the range `[0..Max)`, so you may opt to always perform the normalization. If you want to, you may simplify it to this:

```
func Inc() int64 {
    value := atomic.AddInt64(&index, 1) % Max
    if value == 0 {
        atomic.AddInt64(&index, -Max) // Reset
    }
    return value
}
```

### Reading the counter without incrementing it

The `index` variable should not be accessed directly. If there's a need to read the counter's current value without incrementing it, the following function may be used:

```
func Get() int64 {
    return atomic.LoadInt64(&index) % Max
}
```

### Extreme scenario

Let's analyze an "extreme" scenario. In this, `Inc()` is called 7 times, returning the numbers `1..7`. Now the next call to `Inc()` after the increment will see that the counter is at `8 = Max`. It will then normalize the value to `0` and wants to reset the counter. Now let's say before the reset (which is to add `-8`) is actually executed, 8 other calls happen. They will increment the counter 8 times, and the last one will again see that the counter's value is `16 = 2 * Max`. All the calls will normalize the values into the range `0..7`, and the last call will again go on to perform a reset. Let's say this reset is again delayed (e.g. for scheduling reasons), and yet another 8 calls come in. For the last, the counter's value will be `24 = 3 * Max`, the last call again will go on to perform a reset.

Note that all calls will only return values in the range `[0..Max)`. Once all reset operations are executed, the counter's value will be `0`, properly, because it had a value of `24` and there were 3 "pending" reset operations. In practice there's only a slight chance for this to happen, but this solution handles it nicely and efficiently.

Comment: @Ivan Neither of those are issues. The `index` variable cannot be read, only the return value of `Inc()` is valid, which will always be in the range of `[0..Max)`. My solution does not build on what `Max` is, there are no bit operations involved, only a remainder `%` which works with "any" numbers.

Comment: Yeah, original code does not mention if `index` should never become equal to `Max`, but the non-atomic code does not let it get out of range. If other threads read this variable they might see "invalid" value.

Comment: @Ivan Other goroutines can't read `index` without synchronization anyway, that's undefined behavior in Go in general. If there would be a need to read `index` without incrementing it, it would be a simple `LoadInt64() % Max` operation.

Comment: It is unclear if other goroutines know if `% Max` should be performed. My point was that it is not equivalent to the non-atomic code. And to me it looks like the point of this assignment is to learn how to use CAS loop to implement more complex atomic operations.

Comment: @Ivan Yes, it's true that this solution is not identical, although it solves the original problem in a cleaner and more efficient way. Other goroutines should not mess with `index` anyway, an exported function can be provided to read and return its value if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your goal is to never let `index` has value equal or greater than `Max`. This can be solved using CAS (Compare-And-Swap) loop:

```
const Max = 8
var index int32

func add() int32 {
    var next int32;

    for {
        prev := atomic.LoadInt32(&index)
        next = prev + 1;

        if next >= Max {
            next = 0
        }

        if (atomic.CompareAndSwapInt32(&index, prev, next)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return next
}
```

CAS can be used to implement almost any operation atomically like this. The algorithm is:

1. Load the value
2. Perform the desired operation
3. Use CAS, goto 1 on failure.

Comment: LoadInt32(&index)  whether  can use prev:=index directy, if index is int32.

Comment: @wllenyj `LoadInt32` need to be used to guarantee ordering, normal assignment might not work, depending on compiler and processor architecture.